# a Interview questions about stack cubes using javascript

Tags: javascript, math

You have four colored cubes. Each side of each cube is a single color, and there are four colors: blue (B), red (R), green (G) and yellow (Y) Describing the six faces as front, back, left, right, top, bottom, the cube colors are:

[image]

The objective is to find ways to stack the four cubes as a vertical column so that each side of the column is showing all four colors.

what can i do ,

thanks

ps:

```
function init(){
    var a = [['R','B'],['G','Y'],['B','Y']],
        b = [['R','G'],['G','Y'],['B','B']],
        c = [['Y','B'],['R','G'],['Y','R']],
        d = [['Y','G'],['B','R'],['R','R']]
    var box = [a,b,c,d]
    return box;
}
```

Comment: zjm1126: oh, it's this question again, it's a lot clearer ;-) have an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Search all possible states: there aren't that many (24 rotations per cube, most of which you can filter out). Pseudocode:

```
for cubeLevel0 in rotations(cubes[0]):
    var sidesMatch = function(cube) {
        return cube.N==cubeLevel0.N and cube.S==cubeLevel0.S and ...
    }
    for cubeLevel1 in rotations(cube[1]).filter(sidesMatch):
        for cubeLevel2 in rotations(cube[2]).filter(sidesMatch):
            for cubeLevel3 in rotations(cube[3]).filter(sidesMatch):
                console.log(cubeLevel0, cubeLevel1, cubeLevel2, cubeLevel3)
```

The nested for-loops are ugly, and you can remove them by implementing this as a recursive function. I left it this way for clarity.

To implement the `rotations(cube)` function, you have a few options. The least complicated way is to take a physical cube infront of you, and label each side `{0,1,2,3,4,5}` in some arbitrary order. Then physically perform one of the 24 rotations, and write down the permuted order, then undo the rotation so you're back where you started. Then write the function like so:

```
// You HAVE to manually discover these with the physical method described above
var rotationPermutations = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,4,2,1,5,0], ...(24 of these)...];

function rotations(cube) {  // representing a cube as a 6-tuple
    return rotationPermutations.map(function(permutation) {
        // return [cube[i] for i in permutation]
        return permutation.map(function(x){return cube[x]})
    });    
}
```

You can be smarter about things if you can come up with a way to detect when a permutation is invalid; then you could generate all 48 permutations of the axes (using the `[[axis0top, axis0bottom], [axis1top, axis1bottom], [axis2top, axis2bottom]]` representation, by permuting the axis 3! ways, and flipping each axis 2 ways, so 2^3=8 flip possibilities, 3!*2^3=48) and filter out the half of them with the wrong chirality. Thinking about this would however take longer than writing down the permutations using the manual method described above.

Comment: if i understood this correctly, there are `4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24` possibilities for the order of the cubes. There are 6 ways to turn a cube, so it results in `144` possibilities. Some of thos variations will even be redundant, but doesn't matter... you're right, this number will not be any trouble in js performance.

Comment: @Chips_100: thanks for correcting me, it is indeed 24 and not 12: 4 choices of spin for each of 6 choices of top faces.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.in_array = function(e) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == e) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
Array.prototype.clone = function () {
    return this.slice();
} 

function deepcopy(obj) {
    var out = [],i = 0,len = obj.length;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (obj[i] instanceof Array){
            out[i] = deepcopy(obj[i]);
        }
        else out[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return out;
}

function Cube (id, front, back, left, right, top, bottom) {
    var self = this;
    self.id=id;
    self.front = front;
    self.back = back;
    self.left = left;
    self.right = right;
    self.top = top;
    self.bottom = bottom;
    self.turnMethod1 = function(){//left-front-right-back
        var tmp=self.left;
        self.left=self.front;
        self.front=self.right;
        self.right=self.back;
        self.back=tmp;
    }
    self.turnMethod2 = function(){//left-top-right-bottom
        var tmp=self.left;
        self.left=self.top;
        self.top=self.right;
        self.right=self.bottom;
        self.bottom=tmp;
    }
    self.turnMethod3 = function(){//front-top-back-bottom
        var tmp=self.front;
        self.front=self.top;
        self.top=self.back;
        self.back=self.bottom;
        self.bottom=tmp;
    }

    self.fn = [
        self.turnMethod1,self.turnMethod2,self.turnMethod3
    ]

}

Cube.prototype.toString = function(){
    return this.id+"\t"+this.front+"\t"+this.back+"\t"+this.left+"\t"+this.right+"\t"+this.top+"\t"+this.bottom+"\n";
}


var cube1=new Cube(1,"R","B","G","Y","B","Y");
var cube2=new Cube(2,"R","G","G","Y","B","B");
var cube3=new Cube(3,"Y","B","R","G","Y","R");
var cube4=new Cube(4,"Y","G","B","R","R","R");

function count() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
            cube1.fn[i]()
            for (var a = 0; a < 3; a++) {
                for (var b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
                    cube2.fn[a]()
                    for (var c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                        for (var d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
                            cube3.fn[c]()
                            for (var e = 0; e < 3; e++) {
                                for (var f = 0; f < 4; f++) {
                                    if(done()){
                                        printPermutation();
                                    }
                                    cube4.fn[e]()
                                };

                            };

                        };

                    };
                };

            };
        };

    };
}

function done() {
    var arr = []; /*front validation*/
    arr.push(cube1.front);
    if (arr.in_array(cube2.front)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube2.front);
    }

    if (arr.in_array(cube3.front)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube3.front);
    }
    if (arr.in_array(cube4.front)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube4.front);
    } /*back validation*/
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(cube1.back);
    if (arr.in_array(cube2.back)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube2.back);
    }
    if (arr.in_array(cube3.back)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube3.back);
    }

    if (arr.in_array(cube4.back)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube4.back);
    }
    /*left validation*/
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(cube1.left);
    if (arr.in_array(cube2.left)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube2.left);
    }
    if (arr.in_array(cube3.left)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube3.left);
    }
    if (arr.in_array(cube4.left)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube4.left);
    } /*right validation*/
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(cube1.right);
    if (arr.in_array(cube2.right)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube2.right);
    }
    if (arr.in_array(cube3.right)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube3.right);
    }
    if (arr.in_array(cube4.right)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        arr.push(cube4.right);
    }

    return true;
}

function printPermutation(){
        console.log("----------------------------");
        var  arr = []
        arr.push("Cube\tFront\tBack\tLeft\tRight\tTop\tBottom\n");
        arr.push(cube1.toString());
        arr.push(cube2.toString());
        arr.push(cube3.toString());
        arr.push(cube4.toString());
        console.log(arr.join(""))
}


function main(){
    count()
}

main()
```